# AJAX GET request not working in some places

Tags: ajax, get

I know this kind of question is discussed many times, but I not able to resolve my issue after reading all of them. So please allow me to ask this question -

I'm using below code to send a GET request using AJAX & JQuery -

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   success:function(data){
      alert('success');
   },
   error:function(){
      alert('failure');
   }
});
```

I am getting alert as success, but my action is not getting called.

URL is something like : http://example.com:8080/abc/action1.do?param1=1&param2=2

I have tried with url : /abc/action1.do?param1=1&param2=2, still no luck.

Surprisingly this code (in other places I'm using POST though) is working in all other places in my workspace. I have searched a lot in internet, but still not able to resolve the issue. Can anyone please help me?

- URL is correct. There is no doubt about it. Tried with both relative and absolutr URL.
- I'm sending get request and sending couple of GET parameters as part of requested URL. Not sending data
- I'm not getting any JS error.
- Request is not going to to server (not hitting the action class) so there is no exception in java exception. We are using struts 1.3 framework.

I have added one debug point in my action class also added some sysout to test if everything working fine. Result is, AJAX get request not calling the action class.

**[solution]**

I have solved it using below code -

```
var postParameter = 'param1=a&param2=b';
var action = 'something.do';
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : action,
    async : true,
    dataType: "HTML",
    data : postParameter
    });
```

Comment: Please share more information like exception message, the request or other code of your app. Be sure that the Url is correct. I'm not sure if you sent any parameters.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I've updated my question with more details. If you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by "action is not getting called" ?? what is your action

Comment: Can you post some struts config and the action? And maybe your consoles log? When you used a POST the same AJAX call worked?

Comment: I've tried with POST. Still not working. There is absolutety no problem with struts-config.xml. If I submit the page (document.form[0].submit) action class is getting called. I think there is no problem with the above code, I've posted. There might be something else.

Comment: Please share the code where you think the problem is. We cant help you if you dont help us to understand what you did.

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is. Execution is coming till the point  where we have written AJAX call. So there is no problem on how and from where we are calling this block. There is no problem in Struts-config.xml file. This is a working configuration file for last 4 years. So, I'm not sure is the problem.

Comment: Is the AJAX Call and the Action written by you? Is the code new and wasnt in the existing App? If yes, maybe you have to insert some config in xml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you got some wrong settings in your request

use

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url:  "localhost/get.php",
        type: "get",
        data: {
            a:  "one",
            b:  "two",
            c:  "three"
        },
        success:    func_suc,
        error:      func_err
);
```

Comment: I don't think this will make any difference. However I've tried it and not working.

Comment: May try an other Browser?
And try to debug with Firebug